# Angular Typeahead does not trigger on whitespaces

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I have the following control defined:

```
<input                 id="inputSearchMovies"
                       type="search"
                       ng-model="filterItems"
                       placeholder="Search for movies ..."
                       typeahead="prediction for prediction in getPredictions($viewValue) | limitTo:10"
                       typeahead-min-length='1'
                       typeahead-on-select='onSelectPart($item, $model, $label)'
                       typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"
                       class="form-control shortInputSearch"
                       style="width: 98% !important" />
```

This is bootstrapped to the `getPredictions` function that performs an invocation as I type.

The problem is the typeahead mechanism is not called when I input whitespaces:

- "Lawrence of Arab" -> typing "i", works ok (calls prediction function): "Lawrence of Arabi"
- "Lawrence of Arab" -> typing space does not cause any prediction call: "Lawrence of Arab " (no call made to the server)

How can I fix it to perform a call on each character change (whitespace or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not actually coming from `ui-bootstrap`, it is coming from the way angular handles `input`s. It automatically trims the value of the `input`, before it sets the value of `ng-model`. Since the value ends up being the same as it was before (since it's trimmed), it doesn't consider this a change in value and so it doesn't call the `ngModelController` `$parsers`, which is what `ui-bootstrap` uses to trigger its "getMatchesAsync" (or your "typeahead mechanism").

Don't worry though, this functionality can be turned off by using `ng-trim` like so:

```
<input typehead... ng-trim="false"></input>
```

Here it is in angular docs under Arguments `ngTrim`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

> If set to false Angular will not automatically trim the input. This parameter is ignored for input[type=password] controls, which will never trim the input.
>   (default: true)

I know the title says `type=text`, but I looked at the angular code and this attribute also applies to `type=search`. I can show this code if needed.

Comment: Thanks mate. Works like a charm!